# Signal to CellRendererModeActivatable

Tags: haskell, gtk2hs

The `CellRenderer` of gtk2hs has a property `cellMode`. If it's set to `CellRendererModeActivateble`, what signal gets emitted? I can't find one in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs at https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellRenderer.html state:

> A cell renderer can be “activatable” like GtkCellRendererToggle, which
>   toggles when it gets activated by a mouse click, or it can be
>   “editable” like GtkCellRendererText, which allows the user to edit the
>   text using a GtkEntry. To make a cell renderer activatable or
>   editable, you have to implement the GtkCellRendererClass.activate or
>   GtkCellRendererClass.start_editing virtual functions, respectively.

Therefore, no signals are used by the mode. This seem to be confirmed by the C struct

```
struct GtkCellRendererClass {
  /* vtable - not signals */
  ...
  gboolean           (* activate)          (GtkCellRenderer      *cell,
                                            GdkEvent             *event,
                                            GtkWidget            *widget,
                                            const gchar          *path,
                                            const GdkRectangle   *background_area,
                                            const GdkRectangle   *cell_area,
                                            GtkCellRendererState  flags);
  GtkCellEditable *  (* start_editing)     (GtkCellRenderer      *cell,
                                            GdkEvent             *event,
                                            GtkWidget            *widget,
                                            const gchar          *path,
                                            const GdkRectangle   *background_area,
                                            const GdkRectangle   *cell_area,
                                            GtkCellRendererState  flags);
}
```